Function that reduces the number of element
I have a function, which merges elements if possible.
That is
public IEnumerable<TElement> TryMerge(IEnumerable<TElement> sequence){}

where the returned IEnumerable has less (or equal) elements than the original sequence.
That is.:
var mergedElements = TryMerge(notMergedElements) // mergedElements.Count()<= notMergedElements is alwas true

My issue now is I want an interface for this like:
IMerger {TElement[m] TryMerge(TElement[n] sequence) : where n,m int and m<=n}

So to ensure via signature of method that the returned IEnumerable has less elements. But Somehow it is not possible. Does anyone has an idea?
I already tried to return tuples to control the length of the returned elements. But this only works until 15 elements.

No, this is not possible.

Why call it TryMerge? In .NET Try-methods usually do some operation that isn't guaranteed to succeed and they return a bool to indicate success/failure and the result using an out parameter. This doesn't seem like a method that could fail so I would just call it Merge.

Your best option is to put Debug.Assert(m<=n); at the end of the method. You can't do anything with the signature.

What is the expected behaviour you're looking for?  You can't get compile time feedback from the signature, as the size of sequence is unknown.  At runtime, all it could do would be throw an error or return the original sequence - you can do that by testing the length inside the method and throwing if appropriate....

Are you just wanting some elements skipped or is there some logic to how elements are "merged"?

Is it any different to Take? If you have sequence.Take(number) then the resulting sequence is less than or equal to the length of the source sequence.

The where clause checks something at compile time what you want is something that barks at runtime. So you need to check that in code. Back in the framework days their where CodeContracts to enforce such requirements but lets say they where a weak replacement for real AOP features that C#/The runtime lacks.

Why do you care to enforce this?

This is not a feature C# supports out of the box. Usually you would assert this with unit tests. However, property-based testing seems like a better fit in your scenario.

.NET already has Distinct (and also Union) method. How is your method different?
